# Wordpress plugin cannot cURL or file_get_contents for URLs on the same site

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, file-get-contents

I have a WordPress site that supports IFRAME codes for certain content.  I want for other sites to be able to request an embed code for a given post with a query var.

Example:

```
echo file_get_contents("mysite.com/?get_embed_code=123");
```

Result:

```
<iframe src="mysite.com/permalink-to-post/123"></iframe>
```

It works on other people's sites, but not on my own. Another site can use `file_get_contents()` to request a response from mysite.com, but mysite.com cannot, as it runs into a looping error.

- With cURL it crashes the server.
- With `file_get_contents` it waits and then returns `"unable to establish database connection"`.

Any ideas on ways to approach this that work on my own server as well as on others?

Comment: Well, if you're getting a file that gets that same file, that gets that file etc. it's a loop. Why would you need to get the file you're currently in ?

Comment: If you create a black hole it will all be on you, my friend. But, yeah, why don't you just access the data directly?

Comment: Ha, yeah, the rationale is a bit hard to explain without a little more context. I can indeed access the data directly. Others cannot, however, and I'm trying to create a single plugin that will work for both myself and others in one go. Ah well. Seems like I'll have to do it one way for my own site, and another for others.

Comment: Did you figure out the answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you will need to modify your php.ini file to change [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php).

If you can't modify your php.ini file or that is not an option then you have 2 other options: [`fsockopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php), or [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).